# Play video in full screen and hide Header menu bar in SharePoint online modern site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, spfx, modern-experience

I am creating a landing page in SharePoint Online (modern site not classic). I have below mention client's requirement.

1. Once user hit the SharePoint home page, it should show only the
   video in full screen and after completion of video the page should
   redirect to any other website.
2. Page should have only the video nothing else. Need to the hide the
   top header bar.

What I've tried so far.

1. I added the **full-width section** and linked to the video file. Section
   taking the full width but video is not coming in full screen. Video
   aspect size is correct when i am running the video in browser or any
   video player it is running in full screen.
2. I added the One-column section and added the video using **"File
   viewer" and "embed" web part** and in both cases video is not coming
   full screen.

Is it feasible to achieve these requirements? I searched in google and seems it is a known limitation and didn't get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible using SharePoint OOTB functionalities.

Using SharePoint OOTB, you cannot hide Header menu bar in SharePoint online modern experience.

For you requirements, you need custom solution using SPFx:

1. Create a SPFx web part to show the video on page
2. Hide SharePoint HTML elements (navigation, header, etc.) using custom CSS
3. Add a button to close the video & redirect to another page.

---

**Note**: DOM manipulation & CSS customizations are **not recommended** by Microsoft and some of your customization may break if Microsoft changes HTML element id/classes in new release updates.